# I am writing cloud functions with Node.js, and I want to check a single field with two values (OR CONDITION)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I wrote this code and its not giving me an output as said. The where clause should check the bucket1 field to be `exp` or `facts`. What changes should I need to commit in order to get the said output?

```
 db.collection('xpert_master').doc(xpert_id).collection('responses')
        .where('answer_status', '==', 'custom')
        .where('bucket1', 'in', ['exp','facts'])
        .where('doc_type', '==', 'curated')
        .get()
```

By doing this I am getting :

> Error: Value for argument "opStr" is invalid. Acceptable values are: <, <=, ==, >, >=, array-contains

Even when I use `array-contains` it's still not working.

Answer (score 2):

An in and array-contains-any query have been  released after November, 2019.

So, the firebase version you are using may be old.

Could you use Firebase Admin Node.js SDK 8.8.0 or newer version?

See:

- https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/11/cloud-firestore-now-supports-in-queries.html?linkId=76644965
- https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node#version_880_-_19_november_2019
- https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/releases/tag/v2.6.0

Comment: I am using the latest version i.e, 7.12.1 but still its not working

Comment: I edited my answer. And, v7.12.1 is not exist. check latest sdk versions [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#latest_sdk_versions).